# "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null" when I terminate Tesseract worker in VueJS 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, ocr, tesseract.js

I have this error whenever I try to terminate the Tesseract worker in VueJS.
[image]

The problem starts when I re-uploaded another image to the app, I need to Crtl+Shift+R to temporarily solve it.

This is my Vue

```js
<script>
  import worker from "@/plugin/tesseract";

  export default {
    methods: {
      async recognize() {
        this.$helpers.loading();
        try {
          const result = await worker.recognize(image);
          console.log(result)
          await worker.terminate();
          this.$helpers.close();
        } catch (err) {
          await worker.terminate();
          this.$helpers.showError(err);
        }
      },
    }
  } 
</script>
```

This is my tesseract.js

```js
import {createWorker} from "tesseract.js";

const worker = createWorker({
    // workerPath: 'https://unpkg.com/tesseract.js@v2.0.0/dist/worker.min.js',
    langPath:
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/naptha/tessdata/gh-pages/4.0.0_best/",
    // corePath: 'https://unpkg.com/tesseract.js-core@v2.0.0/tesseract-core.wasm.js',
    logger: (m) => console.log(m)
});

(async () => {
    await worker.load();
    await worker.loadLanguage("vie");
    await worker.initialize("vie");
})();


export default worker;
```

Please help.

Comment: You likely need to recreate a worker after it's terminated. That you don't chain promises inside `(async () => {` is a mistake.